# Autosize columns for TListView

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, tlistview

I want to auto-size all the columns in the TListView. I am using below code, but its not doing any thing.

```
ListView1.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Field Name';
ListView1.Columns.Items[0].Autosize := True;
```

How can i auto-size the columns of TListView in Delphi.

I set my `ViewStyle to vsReport`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got the answer. Setting the column width to `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE` or `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER` solved the problem.

Use `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE` setting to set the column header to the size of the largest subitem text in the column,

and a `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER` setting to set the column header to the size of the text in the column header.

```
uses CommCtrl;

ListView1.Columns[0].Width := LVSCW_AUTOSIZE or LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER;
```

Comment: Of course, it's better to use the appropriate constants: `ColumnHeaderWidth = LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER;` or `ColumnTextWidth = LVSCW_AUTOSIZE;`.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this doesn't work if you set the width from the Object Inspector.

Comment: Unfortunately, this overrides the **MinWidth** property. It should be vice versa.

Comment: should this size be set after every time I add an item or just once?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the constants.

Comment: I think you just need `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER`. That will auto-size the column to fit the largest of the header or the items. Or-ing the two constants doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just set columns width to -1

```
ListView1.Columns[0].Width:=-1;
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
// Assign vsReport;    
ListView1.ViewStyle := vsReport; 

  { // Add your items  }

// Assign vsList again;
ListView1.ViewStyle := vsList;
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked.